# Nicedit.js - cannot add custom button

Tags: javascript, nicedit

I adopted code snippet from [here](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/516/Creating%20a%20Plugin) - just changed my custom button icon path, *but the button doesn't appear*. There are no errors in the console.

```
/**
* nicExample
* @description: An example button plugin for nicEdit
* @requires: nicCore, nicPane, nicAdvancedButton
* @author: Brian Kirchoff
* @version: 0.9.0
*/

/* START CONFIG */
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
  debugger;
  var nicExampleOptions = {
    buttons : {
      'example' : {name : __('Some alt text for the button'), type : 'nicEditorExampleButton'}
    }, iconFiles : {'example' : '/assets/emoticons/aa.gif'}
  };

  var nicEditorExampleButton = nicEditorButton.extend({   
    mouseClick : function() {
      alert('The example save button icon has been clicked!');
    }
  });

  nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicExampleOptions);
});
```

Also I add my custom button name to editor button list:

```
  this.instantiate_nicedit_for_textarea = function(textArea){
    var nic_editor = new nicEditor({buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','example'], iconsPath : '/assets/nicEditorIcons.gif'})

    nic_editor.addInstance(textArea.id); 

    var topbar_id = $(textArea).prevAll('div.widget_topbar').last().children('ul').children('li.nic_panel').attr('id');
    nic_editor.setPanel(topbar_id);
  };
```

**UPDATE: Firefox 18.02, Chrome 22.0.1229.94**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tracing into nicEdit code I found that buttons actually appear on the screen when setPanel() API function is being called.

*setPanel()* draws standard buttons, then it passes *'panel'* event to *fireEvent()* API function which then invokes *loadPanel()*, which in turn calls *addButton()*, which tests button.type by evaluating it:

```
addButton : function(buttonName,options,noOrder) {
  var button = options.buttons[buttonName];
  var type = (button['type']) ? eval('(typeof('+button['type']+') == "undefined") ? null : '+button['type']+';') : nicEditorButton;

  // <== here type is null, cause I defined button['type'] as local variable in separate file

  var hasButton = bkLib.inArray(this.buttonList,buttonName);
  if(type && (hasButton || this.ne.options.fullPanel)) {
    this.panelButtons.push(new type(this.panelElm,buttonName,options,this.ne));
    if(!hasButton) {
      this.buttonList.push(buttonName);
    }
  }
},
```

in the snippet above the code `eval('(typeof('+button['type']+') == "undefined")` returnes true as I defined the button type as a local variable:

```
var nicEditorExampleButton = nicEditorButton.extend({   
    mouseClick : function() {
      alert('The example save button icon has been clicked!');
    }
  });
```

The button appeared as soon as I defined the button type as global:

```
nicEditorExampleButton = nicEditorButton.extend({   
  mouseClick : function() {
    alert('The example save button icon has been clicked!');
  }
});
```

I think type existance which nicEdit does should perform more clear and reliable way to prevent global namespace pollution, maybe as of `(typeof(button['type']) == "undefined")`

Answer (score 2):

Based on save button plugin, this how your code should look:

```
var nicExampleOptions = {
    buttons : {
        'example' : {name : __('Example'), type : 'nicEditorExampleButton'}
    }
};

var nicEditorExampleButton = nicEditorButton.extend({
    init : function() {
        // your init code
    },
    mouseClick : function() {
        alert('hallo!'); // Your code here
    }
});

nicEditors.registerPlugin(nicPlugin,nicExampleOptions);
```

As a best practice, I sugest you add this code in a separated file, and make sure that is loaded **after** `nicEdit.js`. Then, you can add the button to your instance's *buttonList*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok. This code works for me with niceEditor basic and documented configuration.

Comment: +1 i have used your answer and its work nicely. i have more question about this how to add image on button. because no image is showing on that toolbar

Comment: @SatishSharma at the moment, I didn't find a easy way to add images to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

My nicElement loading process is done by this function :

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
new nicEditor({buttonList: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'ol', 'ul', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontFormat', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'indent', 'outdent', 'link', 'unlink', 'striketrhough', 'forecolor', 'bgcolor', 'image', 'upload', 'xhtml','example']}).panelInstance('textareaExample');
```

});

where `textareaExample` is the id of the textarea.

Adding your button name (in my case `example`) to the `buttonList` should add your button.

So look where you have new `nicEditor();`

Some examples of `nicEdit` loading options may be seen [here](http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=2).

Answer (score 0):

Can, Update line "buttonList" to

```
buttonList : ['save','example','bold','italic','underline','left','center','right','justify','ol','ul','fontSize','fontFamily','fontFormat','indent','outdent','image','upload','link','unlink','forecolor','bgcolor'],`enter code here`
```

for show button 
in file js main (example)

```
var nicEditorConfig = bkClass.extend({
buttons : {
    'test' : {name : __('Click to Test'), command : 'Test'},
    'bold' : {name : __('Click to Bold'), command : 'Bold', tags : ['B','STRONG'], css : {'font-weight' : 'bold'}, key : 'b'},
    'italic' : {name : __('Click to Italic'), command : 'Italic', tags : ['EM','I'], css : {'font-style' : 'italic'}, key : 'i'},
    'underline' : {name : __('Click to Underline'), command : 'Underline', tags : ['U'], css : {'text-decoration' : 'underline'}, key : 'u'},
    'left' : {name : __('Left Align'), command : 'justifyleft', noActive : true},
    'center' : {name : __('Center Align'), command : 'justifycenter', noActive : true},
    'right' : {name : __('Right Align'), command : 'justifyright', noActive : true},
    'justify' : {name : __('Justify Align'), command : 'justifyfull', noActive : true},
    'ol' : {name : __('Insert Ordered List'), command : 'insertorderedlist', tags : ['OL']},
    'ul' :  {name : __('Insert Unordered List'), command : 'insertunorderedlist', tags : ['UL']},
    'subscript' : {name : __('Click to Subscript'), command : 'subscript', tags : ['SUB']},
    'superscript' : {name : __('Click to Superscript'), command : 'superscript', tags : ['SUP']},
    'strikethrough' : {name : __('Click to Strike Through'), command : 'strikeThrough', css : {'text-decoration' : 'line-through'}},
    'removeformat' : {name : __('Remove Formatting'), command : 'removeformat', noActive : true},
    'indent' : {name : __('Indent Text'), command : 'indent', noActive : true},
    'outdent' : {name : __('Remove Indent'), command : 'outdent', noActive : true},
    'hr' : {name : __('Horizontal Rule'), command : 'insertHorizontalRule', noActive : true}
},
iconsPath : '../nicEditorIcons.gif',
buttonList : ['save','example','bold','italic','underline','left','center','right','justify','ol','ul','fontSize','fontFamily','fontFormat','indent','outdent','image','upload','link','unlink','forecolor','bgcolor'],
iconList : {"bgcolor":1,"forecolor":2,'test':3,"bold":3,"center":4,"hr":5,"indent":6,"italic":7,"justify":8,"left":9,"ol":10,"outdent":11,"removeformat":12,"right":13,"save":24,"strikethrough":15,"subscript":16,"superscript":17,"ul":18,"underline":19,"image":20,"link":21,"unlink":22,"close":23,"arrow":25}
```

});